# blackberry webworks: creating directory in phone memory or sd card

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-playbook, blackberry-webworks

```
function createDir()
{
    try
    {
        blackberry.io.dir.createNewDir("file:///store/home/user/FolderName");
        alert("createDir event fired succefully");
    }
    catch(ex)
    {
        alert("createDir event faces following error: "+ex);
    }

}
`
```

i don't understand what i did wrong here => **blackberry.io.dir.createNewDir("file:///store/home/user/FolderName");** whats the correct syntax??  the following error fires when bb goes to this code block: **"Null"**. why?

---

this is weird. the finction is working when i do code like this. you might notice, i missed the '/' character there. but that is not the issue. first, i tried it that way too. someone care to answer this weird behavior?

```
function createDir()
{
    try
    {
        var path="file:///store/home/user/SomeFolderName/";
        blackberry.io.dir.createNewDir(path);
        alert("createDir event fired succefully");
    }
    catch(ex)
    {
        alert("createDir event faces following error: "+ex);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

in config.xml - `<feature id="blackberry.io.dir" />` is enabled?